# Display report in visual force page

Tags: visualforce, reporting

I want to display report table in visualforce page.I am looking for solution that available but so far I found :

- Using Iframe : This serve exactly what I want but I don't want to use iframe because of Clickjack proctection is enabled.
- Using Apex Analytic API: This is only for displaing chart.I want to display report table, not chart.
- create datatable from scratch : If I create new datatable in visualforce page, everytime the report is changed example filter,column then I need to change the code.

Is there anyway to display Report in visualforce page?

Comment: Hi I know it's old but did you ever find a solution to this one ? even the iframe solution doesn't seem to be working now.